# Basic definition of duty cycle

Tags: duty-cycle

**Does the definition of duty cycle indicate only the percentage of time that the level is asserted?** 
For example, if a 10 Hz square wave is de-asserted for 5 of those 10Hz cycles and asserted for 5 of the 10Hz cycles, would that represent a 50% duty cycle? If I represent each of the de-asserted 10 Hz cycles in a single second as a 0 and each of the asserted 10 Hz cycles in that same second as a 1, I could represent a 50% duty cycle as 0000011111. But if it is only the percentage that matters, I could also get 50% by the sequence 0101010101. In the definition of duty cycle, is it necessarily the case that the asserted periods be consecutive and that the de-asserted periods also be consecutive?

Comment: duty cycle percentage is measured within a single cycle of the signal ..... `high for 5 seconds and low for 5 seconds equals 50% duty cycle` .....  `high for 1 second and low for 9 seconds equals 10% duty cycle`

Comment: I am tempted to write a one word answer: "Yes." It probably wouldn't be well received, but it would technically answer your question perfectly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duty_cycle - For example 1010 would be a duty cycle of 50%, as would a repeating signal of 1111 1011 1111 1111 0000 0000 0000 0010 (and countless other permutations).

Comment: When discussing duty cycle, there is generally an assumption that the frequency is fixed. So the percent is always calculated over a single period. If the output is de-asserted for an entire period, you might refer to that as a skipped pulse. Some regulators will go into a skip-pulse mode under certain conditions.

Answer (score 1):

If you had the pattern 0101010101, you’d still have a 50% duty cycle. However, the frequency would be higher. If 0000011111 represents 10 Hz, then 0101010101 would represent 50 Hz.

Comment: Or is it 10Hz and 1 Hz?

Comment: @TonyEErocketscientist assuming each bit represents 10ms, then 0000011111 represents 50ms on/50 ms off = 100ms cycle = 10 Hz and 01 (repeated as many times as desired) is 10ms on/10 ms off = 20 ms cycle = 50Hz.

Comment: I want to electronically control a normally closed purge control solenoid (Honda Part No.: 36162-PAA-A02 / DENSO 136200-1570 PCS14). With a warm engine and sufficiently high RPMs, the car applies a PWM duty cycle to the valve. Can a test tool drive a PWM duty cycle? Power application must be long enough to actuate, but not long enough for current to cause overheating. Most consumer PWM devices have too high a frequency (e.g., 13KHz PWM DC motor speed control).  An adjustable rate in 0.5 Hz to 5Hz range should work. Perhaps I should skip PWM and use an adjustable rate 12V flasher relay?

Comment: For clarification, my initial question did assume each bit represents 10 ms. I now understand that “0000011111 represents 50ms on/50 ms off = 100ms cycle = 10 Hz”, while “0101010101 would represent 50 Hz”. I gather that people seem to use PWM for (1) dimmer control for LEDs, and (2) speed control for DC motors. For dimmer control, is PWM simply providing a lower average voltage? What is the concept for speed control of a DC motor? Given the basic nature of my questions, is there a book or subject matter that I should look into for more information?